# Return an array in c with pointers

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I am trying to make a program that makes simple things. Actually, I know how to do it but in an easier way without pointers and stuff. However, I wondered how I could do it differently (like I did below). Obviously, there is something I miss about pointers, I did the math, but still I cannot get its philosophy.
Thank you!

```
long *read_array(int n1, int n2)
{
    int i, j;
    long a[n1][n2];
    for(i=0;i<n1;i++)
        for(j=0;j<n2;j++)
            printf("Fill the table");
    a[i][j]=GetLong();
    return a;
}

long *Min_of_Rows(int m, int n, long *a)
{
    long B[];
    int i, j;
    for(i=0;i<m;i++)
        B[i]=a[i][0];
    for(j=0;j<n;j++)
        if (a[i][j]<B[i])
            B[i]=a[i][j];

    return B;
}

void *Print_B_array (int M, long *b)
{
    int i;
    for(i=0; i<M; i++)
        printf("%ld\n",b[i]);
}

main()
{
    long *a, *b;
    int n1, n2;

    printf("give rows");
    n1=GetInteger();

    printf("give columns");
    n2=GetInteger();

    a=read_array(n1, n2);
    b=Min_of_rows(n1, n2, a);
    Print_B_Array(n1, b);

}
```

Comment: Please fix your indentation - it is absolutely awful to look at.

Comment: Also, you can't return the address of a local variable of a function and then use it after that function returns - (e.g. `return a` in `read_array`). You need to allocate space for the array with `malloc`.

Comment: and `read_array` return `long*`, not `int*`.

Comment: `long a[n1][n2];` This won't compile, since `n1` and `n2` are not constant. On this line (`for (j = 0; j>n; j++)`), `n` is not defined. `long B[];` this is not valid C. Also, what is `GetLong`?

Comment: As I can see I cannot escape the allocation :( I will try malloc!

Comment: `long B[];` is illegal

Comment: @cmbasnett array dimensions do not have to be constant

Comment: @MattMcNabb When he/she is trying to instantiate it like that (`long a[n1][n2];`), the dimensions do need to be constant.

Comment: @cmbasnett no they don't

Comment: @MattMcNabb I stand corrected, shows how much I program C nowadays. :P EDIT: Just did a more thorough check, it seems to depend on the compiler.  VS2013 doesn't like it, gcc seems to have no issue.

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

long *read_array(int n1, int n2){
    int i, j;
    long a[n1][n2];

    printf("Fill the table\n");
    for(i=0;i<n1;i++){
        for(j=0;j<n2;j++){
            a[i][j]=GetLong();
        }
    }
    long *ret = malloc(sizeof(a));
    memcpy(ret, a, sizeof(a));
    return ret;
}

long *Min_of_Rows(int m, int n, long *a){
    long *B = malloc(m*sizeof(*B));
    int i, j;
    long (*A)[n] = (void*)a;

    for(i=0;i<m;i++){
        B[i]=A[i][0];
        for(j=0;j<n;j++){
            if(A[i][j]<B[i])
                B[i]=A[i][j];
        }
    }
    return B;
}

void *Print_B_Array (int M, long *b){
    int i;
    for(i=0; i<M; i++)
        printf("%ld\n", b[i]);
}

int main(void){
    long *a, *b;
    int n1, n2;

    printf("give rows:");
    n1=GetInteger();

    printf("give columns:");
    n2=GetInteger();

    a=read_array(n1, n2);
    b=Min_of_Rows(n1, n2, a);
    printf("min of rows\n");
    Print_B_Array(n1, b);
    free(a);
    free(b);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `read_array` uses stack space when it doesn't have to (could cause stack overflow if the dimensions are big) so I'd suggest `long (*a)[n2] = malloc( n1 * sizeof *a );`, then the same `for` loop, then `return (long *)a;`